# android widget and localservice bind

Tags: android, service, android-activity, media-player

I writing player, it has main activity that runs localservice.
I can't find how bind localservice to widget.
When i trying to bind it like in activity it fails.

Plz help me.

Adding #1
How can I contact with background service when?
http://www.developer.com/ws/data/article.php/10944_3843561_1/Handling-Lengthy-Operations-with-Android-App-Widgets.htm

here i found something, but it doen't work for me.

Comment: what do you mean with local service? are you using gps module?

Comment: Actully no, I make music player

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bind to a service from an `AppWidgetProvider`.

Comment: @Spin7ion: that is impossible to answer in the abstract. You need to redesign your application such that you do not need to try to bind to a service from an `AppWidgetProvider`. For example, you could use `startService()` to send an `Intent` from your `AppWidgetProvider` to your service's `onStart()` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can bind to a service from a AppWidgetProvider like so:

```
context.getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, ServiceConnection, Flags);
```

The context is the parameter on the onUpdate method.